# How can I generate unique random patterns (similar to the ones in Nutella jars)?

Tags: neural-networks, ai-design, python, image-processing, image-generation

How can I generate unique patterns, as they did for these Nutella jars? See, for example, the video [Algorithm designs seven million different jars of Nutella](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHYakhyvJps).

[image]

Comment: You are probably looking at something like randomly generated constructive grammars. Not sure if that is considered an AI technique. Nowadays you might also choose to use a GAN (which is definitely considered a modern AI technique), but to do so with abstract shapes and patterns like in the picture you would proabably generate a training set using some randomly generated constructive grammars . . .

Answer (score 1):

Some excerpts from     [Nutella 'Hired' an Algorithm to Design New Jars. And It Was a Sell-Out Success](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14553261):

The "algorithm" is called HP Mosaic and is included free in HP SmartStream Designer for HP printers.

More about how the algorithm works here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hp-mosaic-20-steven-chow

HP Mosaic takes the vector PDF file as input (also known as a Seed file), and generates a large number of variations on the file by transforming it — scaling, transposition, and rotation — randomly.